# Windows Batch : Iterate through file names while performing an action on each one?

Tags: loops, batch-file

Currently my loop reads files contained (ending in .al).
But when I try to Set/Alter the file names it simply skips to the final file and works with that one. (xxx.al)
I have attempted to use EnableDelayedExpansion but still can not resolve.
Final output should be as follows

```
spconv -if raw -of wav xxx.al xxx.wav
```

But instead of just xxx.al file, all files contained should be iterated through. i.e

```
spconv -if raw -of wav abc.al abc.wav
spconv -if raw -of wav def.al def.wav
```

Current batch command is as follows

```
@echo off

for %%d in (*.al) do (
set str=%%d
set string=%%d:C:\test\test\=%
set string2=%string:.al=%
spconv -if raw -of wav %string% %string2%.wav
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for %%d in (*.al) do spconv -if raw -of wav %%d %~nd.wav
```

see `for /?` - especially the last part of it.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`for /?`  in the command-line gives help about this syntax.

> In addition, substitution of FOR
>   variable references has been enhanced.
>   You can now use the following optional
>   syntax:
>
> ```
> %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
> %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
> %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
> %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
> %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
> %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
> %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
> %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
> %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
> %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
> %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
>                environment variable and expands %I to the
>                fully qualified name of the first one found.
>                If the environment variable name is not
>                defined or the file is not found by the
>                search, then this modifier expands to the
>                empty string
> ```
>
> The modifiers can be combined to get
>   compound results:
>
> ```
> %~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
> %~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
> %~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
> %~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH
>                environment variable for %I and expands to the
>                drive letter and path of the first one found.
> %~ftzaI     - expands %I to a DIR like output line
> ```
>
> In the above examples %I and PATH can
>   be replaced by other valid values. 
>   The %~ syntax is terminated by a valid
>   FOR variable name. Picking upper case
>   variable names like %I makes it more
>   readable and avoids confusion with the
>   modifiers, which are not case
>   sensitive.

There are different letters you can use like `f` for "full path name", `d` for drive letter, `p` for path, and they can be combined. `%~` is the beginning for each of those sequences and a number `I` denotes it works on the parameter `%I` (where `%0` is the complete name of the batch file, just like you assumed).

In batch file you should write `%%I` instead of `%I` to escape `%` 
character.

And your batch looks like this one :

```
@echo off
for %%I in (*.al) do spconv -if raw -of wav %%I %~nI.wav
Pause
```